# how to browse through folders in system?

Tags: c#, winforms, explorer

In my windows application I wan user to browse through folders, drives and on selecting a folder it will display the content of that folder, same like windows explorer. I know there is existing control FolderBrowserDialog, but thats a separate dialog doesn't provide facility like explorer. How can I achieve this?

Edit:
I am developing a utility for my personal use that will do some file management, copy, paste stuff and all.
I found this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileBrowser.aspx
but this is having many bugs.

Comment: What will your application do with the displayed folder? Maybe you will be better off writing a shell extension, or hosting Explorer via OLE.

Comment: @Anton Tykhyy : updated my question..

Comment: http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm, it might work. I am afraid if it is paid or having any licensing issues.

Comment: sink your data ? Did you mean sync ? Does totalcommander not satisfy your needs

Comment: Alternatively, if you want realiza something personal, you can use System.IO namespace and all Object expose by this like Directory and File!

Comment: @Reno : thanks for link, just checked it. It is having lot of features but it is paid..trying to develop myself.

Comment: @RoBYCoNTe : It just have names, doesn't display files and folders in explorer way

Comment: @vik what exactly is missing in `FolderBrowserDialog`? Anyway to notify someone it's enough to use the first 3 letters e.g. @RoB no need to type the full name. :)

Comment: @Sha thanks....learnt something new :)  FolderBrowserDialog opens a separate dialog, I want to display everything on form like in explorer

Comment: @vik no problem, glad to spread this around. :) I fear you'll have to write your own code for this using `System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories()` giving it some root, and for display you have `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` control.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to build an application around (among others) the [System.Windows.Forms.TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx) and [System.Windows.Forms.ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) controls.